# C++ outputs garbage values sometimes

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I am trying to create a game like a simple PapersPlease but when my program outputs a random name from my array it outputs a garbage value (�) and I'm not sure on how to fix this issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int random_number;
string RandomName;

string names[12] = {"Lucas","Rendeev","J2Trappy","D2Savvy","James","Daniel","Abraham","Shaggy","Luke","Harry","Rick","Morty"};


int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    random_number = rand() % 12;
    RandomName = names[random_number - 1];
    cout << "Name: "<<RandomName<<"\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
Name: �
�t
```

Comment: Hint: What happens if `random_number` is `0`?

Comment: What is `- 1` for?

Comment: What range of values do you think `rand() % 12` produces? It looks like you think the range is `[1, 12]` but you should look at this more closely. :)

Comment: Side note: `rand` was a good balance between the amount of computing power available and the needs of most people back when C was getting rolling and being formalized. Today there are more powerful tools available in the [random library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). [Here is a video that covers the improvements and how to use them](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `RandomName = names[random_number - 1];`

if random_number is equal to `0` then `random_number - 1` will be equal to `-1`, which is out of range of the array.
Make sure to always be inside of **0** and **11** (size of the array - 1)

Comment: They might not understand why `random_number` could ever be `0`. It may help to explain what range of values `rand() % 12` produces.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that myself!